# Method gets called where I don't expect it to

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a multithreading code example for the well known Philosopher problem. In this scenario 5 Philosophers try to eat, but they share the same fork with the next Philosopher sitting next to them.

I have a problem understanding the way a Thread in this code works:

When I observe the output of this code, it looks like `pickup` executes `test` after `wait`. But how is that possible, considering `test` comes clearly before `wait`?

**Example output:**

> Philosoph 0 is hungry
>   Philosoph 0 is eating
>   Philosophers eating: 0 .
>   Philosoph 3 is hungry
>   Philosoph 3 is eating
>   Philosophers eating: 0 3 .
>   Philosoph 1 is hungry
>   Philosoph 2 is hungry
>   Philosoph 4 is hungry
>   Philosoph 0 is thinking
>   Philosoph 1 is eating

"Philosoph 1 is eating" gets printed by `test(1)`, which is called by `pickup(1)`, but how is that possible?

**class Philosoph:**

```
class Philosoph extends Thread {
    Dining_Philosophers dp;
    int name;

    public Philosoph(int n, Dining_Philosophers d) {
        name = n;
        dp = d;
    }

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            thinking();
            dp.pickup(name);
            eating();
            dp.putdown(name);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Dining_Philosophers dp = new Dining_Philosophers();
        Philosoph p0 = new Philosoph(0, dp);
        Philosoph p1 = new Philosoph(1, dp);
        Philosoph p2 = new Philosoph(2, dp);
        Philosoph p3 = new Philosoph(3, dp);
        Philosoph p4 = new Philosoph(4, dp);
        p0.start();
        p1.start();
        p2.start();
        p3.start();
        p4.start();
    }

    void thinking() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    }

    void eating() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    }
}
```

**class Dining_Philosophers:**

```
class Dining_Philosophers {
    static int thinking = 0;
    static int hungry = 1;
    static int eating = 2;
    int[] state = new int[5];

    public Dining_Philosophers() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            state[i] = thinking;
        }
    }

    public synchronized void pickup(int i) {
        //The Thread executes this function, but 
        // when it executes the wait function und wake up after the notification by another
        // thread then it executes only the test-function. But why only the it and not the  
        // other Code like the "System.out.println("Philosoph " + i + " is hungry");" ?
        state[i] = hungry;
        System.out.println("Philosoph " + i + " is hungry");
        test(i);
        while (state[i] != eating) {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        }
    }

    public synchronized void putdown(int i) {
        state[i] = thinking;
        System.out.println("Philosoph " + i + " is thinking");
        test((i + 4) % 5);
        test((i + 1) % 5);
    }

    public void test(int k) {
        int i;
        if ((state[(k + 4) % 5] != eating) && (state[k] == hungry) && (state[(k + 1) % 5] != eating)) {
            state[k] = eating;
            System.out.println("Philosoph " + k + " is eating");
            System.out.print("Philosophers eating: ");
            for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                if (state[i] == eating)
                    System.out.print(i + " ");
            System.out.println(".");
            notifyAll();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing that `test` is not only called by `pickup`, but also by `putdown`.

The *"Philosoph 1 is eating"* output in your example wasn't called by `pickup(1)`, but by `putdown(0)`. `putdown` calls `test` for the philosopher before and after.

The expressions `(i + 4) % 5` and `(i + 1) % 5` might be a bit confusing, but `(i + 4) % 5` gives the previous philosopher:

> (0 + 4) % 5 = 4
>   (1 + 4) % 5 = 0
>   (2 + 4) % 5 = 1
>   (3 + 4) % 5 = 2
>   (4 + 4) % 5 = 3

and `(i + 1) % 5` gives the next philosopher:

> (0 + 1) % 5 = 1
>   (1 + 1) % 5 = 2
>   (2 + 1) % 5 = 3
>   (3 + 1) % 5 = 4
>   (4 + 1) % 5 = 0